# How to add event to every image using ES5

Tags: javascript

I am adding event listener to every image in document.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
    let img = document.images[i];
    img.addEventListener('click', function (event) { 
        var data = {uri: img.src}; 
    });
}
```

But I can't use es6 so `let` is making me issue. If I put `var` instead of `let` only last image has event.
How to use es5 to add event to each image?

Comment: All your event listener does is define a variable? Which is then disposed off straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way using `var` and `this`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
  document.images[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var data = {
      uri: this.src
    };
  });
}
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
  document.images[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var data = {
      uri: this.src
    };
    console.log(data)
  });
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x200">
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x300">
```

Comment: I use this in specific environment and this is only that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of creating elements and adding an event listener to each using regular old ES5.

```js
function createClickableElements() {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'Click Here!';
    arr.push(div);
  }
  return arr;
}

var elems = createClickableElements();

var createClickHandler = function(arg) {
  return function() {
    console.log(arg);
  };
}

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].onclick = createClickHandler(i);
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(elems[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other examples suggest, there is no need of creating a closure for each image, or assigning a new anonymous function to each image. And ES5 already offers `Array.from` and `Array.prototype.forEach`. Making use of it supports writing better readable code that just uses two functions - one for assigning the click handler and another one that will handle the data creation of any image, thus offering a less memory consuming approach too ...

```js
function createImageData(evt) {
  var data = { uri: evt.target.src };
  console.log('createImageData - data : ', data);
}
function assignClickHandler(elmImage) {
  elmImage.addEventListener('click', createImageData, false);
  console.log('assignClickHandler - elmImage : ', elmImage);
}
Array.from(document.images).forEach(assignClickHandler);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; }
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x200">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x300">
```

... one might even think about making use of [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)